# Convert ActionMailer.Mvc from C# to VB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

The original documentation exists [here](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home).

I have already converted the controller action:

```
Imports ActionMailer.Net.Mvc

    Public Class EmailController
        Inherits MailerBase

        Public Function VerificationEmail(ByVal model As RegisterModel) As EmailResult

            [To].Add(model.Email)
            From = "me@my.org"
            Subject = "Thanks for registering with us!"
            Return Email("VerificationModel", model)

        End Function

    End Class
```

And, the view (`EmailVerification.html.vbhtml`):

```
@modelType GemcoBlog.RegisterModel

@Code
    Layout = Nothing
End code

Welcome to My Cool Site, @Model.UserName

We need you to verify your email.  Click this nifty link to get verified!

@Html.ActionLink("Verify", "Account", New With {.code = Model.Email})

Thanks!
```

**But, how do I convert this C# code to call the function from within my Register method to VB?**

```
new MailController().VerificationEmail(newUser).Deliver();
```

I haven't found anything on the internet describing how to do this in VB, so maybe this post will be helpful for those looking.

**As a side note:  Could someone please explain to me this syntax `[To].Add(model.Email)`?  I haven't seen that before.  Thanks.**

Comment: The brackets force the compiler to recognize the text between them as variable or type name in your code rather than as a VB keyword.  In this case, the word "To" is a VB keyword as used in a for loop (e.g. `For x = 1 To 10`.  So, unless you escape it with brackets, the compiler will think it's an invalid use of the `To` keyword.

Comment: In VB.NET it would be the same syntax, except of the ";" at the end (it is just plain simple method chaining). Your last question: it is because `To` cannot be an identifier (it is some reserved word I believe) and by adding the brackets around it (`[To]`) you can use `To` as an identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim controller = New MailController()
Dim email = controller.VerificationEmail(newUser)
email.Deliver()
```

or if you prefer one liners:

```
Call New MailController().VerificationEmail(newUser).Deliver()
```

> As a side note: Could someone please explain to me this syntax
>   [To].Add(model.Email)? I haven't seen that before. Thanks.

`To` is a reserved word in VB. Wrapping it in square brackets ensures that you are not clashing with this reserved keyword.

The equivalent in C# is the `@` keyword:

```
int @int = 123;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  When I write `new MailController().VerificationEmail(newUser).Deliver()` it gives me a syntax error on "new."

Comment: It literally just says, "Syntax error."  It gives no further info.  It has a blue underline in visual studio.

Comment: @user1477388 It's `New` not `new`. Capital `N`

Comment: @jgauffin, VB.NET is not case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, Darin. (Call http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz(v=vs.80).aspx)